# Running Ant task on maven: copy, delete files within the projects

Tags: maven, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I had a `deploy.ant` file in which the whole build process was done, including copying files, executing the protobuf compiler and all that. Now that I am switching to maven, I have `pom.xml` files which are supposed to do these tasks. I am done almost all, except the `deploy.ant` script which I am left with.

This script has cleaning, preparing, building and deploying targets. What I need from here is cleaning, preparing and **only some part** of the building target, because the other parts are done by the other `pom.xml`s.

So in my `deploy.ant` I have the following code snippets:

```
<!-- just copying sh and ant files to release folder. -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${install.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${install.dir}" />
        <copy file="${template.dir}/run.all.ant" todir="${install.dir}" />
        <copy file="${template.dir}/run.all.sh" todir="${install.dir}" />
        <copy file="${template.dir}/kill.all.sh" todir="${install.dir}" />
        <copy file="${template.dir}/packLogs.sh" todir="${install.dir}" />
    </target>
    .
    .
    .
    .
<!-- copy template files and configurations -->
        <if>
            <available file="${component.project.dir}/conf/config.properties" />
            <then>
                <copy file="${component.project.dir}/conf/config.properties" todir="${component.release.dir}/conf" />
            </then>
            <else>
                <echo message="${component.project.dir} does not provide a bundle config - using default from release bundle" />
                <copy file="${template.dir}/config.properties" todir="${component.release.dir}/conf" />
            </else>
        </if>
        <if>
            <available file="${component.project.dir}/plans" type="dir" />
            <then>
                <copy todir="${component.release.dir}/plans">
                    <fileset dir="${component.project.dir}/plans" includes="**" />
                </copy>
            </then>
        </if> 
         .
         .
          <copy file="../group1/someProject.mw/conf/log4j.xml" todir="${component.release.dir}/conf" />
            <copy file="${template.dir}/run.ant" todir="${component.release.dir}" />
            <copy file="${template.dir}/run.sh" todir="${component.release.dir}" />
```

and this is the maven part I've come up with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>Copying .sh and .ant files to release folder</echo>
                    <basename file="${component.project.dir}" property="component.name" />
                    <property name="component.release.dir" value="${install.dir}/${component.name}" />
                    <delete dir="${install.dir}" />
                    <mkdir dir="${install.dir}" />
                    <copy file="${template.dir}/run.all.ant" todir="${install.dir}" />
                    <copy file="${template.dir}/run.all.sh" todir="${install.dir}" />
                    <copy file="${template.dir}/kill.all.sh" todir="${install.dir}" />
                    <copy file="${template.dir}/packLogs.sh" todir="${install.dir}" />
                    <copy file="../group1/someProject.mw/conf/log4j.xml" todir="${component.release.dir}/conf" />
                    <copy file="${template.dir}/run.ant" todir="${component.release.dir}" />
                    <copy file="${template.dir}/run.sh" todir="${component.release.dir}" />
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

But as you can see I am quite confused with all these paths and how to integrate them in maven. I suspect the code I shared is correct, as maven would have no idea about what the `"${install.dir}"` is.

So my question is, how to integrate such tasks in maven using this plugin? Is it simply copy-pasting the ant snippets into the tags of the plugin? If so, how will it ever understand what is meant by the ant properties; paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to assemble some files into a meaningfull package, available as a directory.

Obviously, there is a maven plugin for that : [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

To achieve your goal, you will first have to reference that plugin in your pom :

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-install-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <inherited>true</inherited>
          <configuration>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/main/assemblies/install.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <attach>true</attach>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Then you'll obviously have to create the install.xml assembly file, conforming to [assembly schema](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html).

Something like that should do the trick

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>install</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${template.dir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${install.dir}</outputDirectory>
            <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <includes>
                <include>run.all.ant</include>
                <include>run.all.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Well, this assembly is not complete, but I guess you'll understand the idea.

Comment: The build process is supposed be done by other means, what I want is to simply copy/paste files into relevant project folders. Do I still need this "assembly" plugin?

Comment: In fact, it will separate the way your distribution folder is made from the moment it is invoked. When using maven, I often find it to be way better than using maven-ant-plugin. So, yeah, you'll need it, just to clarify your build.

Comment: There are some issues about this. First, I need it running only through `install` phase, is this possible? Also, can this handle if-else condition?

Comment: Nevertheless I accept the answer since it does solve the problem.

Comment: Does maven recognize properties like `${template.dir}` ? Do I need to write the name of the actual component there all the time? If so, this is not handy. Because I have tons of components and I cannot copy-paste the same code snippet for each, I'd end up in thousands of lines of maven code just for this, which is unprofessional. I need to utilize properties like `${component.dir}`, `${component.release.dir}` and etc. And I should be able to use loops like `for-each`. Can you confirm if this is possible with this plugin?